# How to add css elements to coundownt clock

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im coding(copied) this countdown clock to july first.
With .foo class i managed to make the clock color red and font size 50px but how can i make a seperate border for each days,hours,minutes,seconds?

This is one of my first codes so explain it simple please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">   

    <style>

    h1{color:brown;
    }
    p
    {font-size:50px;
    color:lightcoral;
    }

    .foo{color:red;
    font-size:50px;



     }

        </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:cyan" "text-align:center">

<h1> </h1>

<h2> </h2>



   <div id="clockdiv" class="foo">

    Days:<span class="days"></span><br>
    Hours: <span class="hours"></span><br>
    Minutes: <span class="minutes"></span><br>
    Seconds: <span class="seconds"></span>
    </div>








    <script>
    var deadline = '7/1/2017';
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

    function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
     var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
     var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
     var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
     var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
     var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
    return {
      'total': t,
      'days': days,
      'hours': hours,
      'minutes': minutes,
      'seconds': seconds
    };

    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime){
      var clock = document.getElementById(id);
      var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
      var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
      var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
      var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

      var timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
        clock.innerHTML = 'days: ' + t.days + '<br>' +
                      'hours: '+ t.hours + '<br>' +
                      'minutes: ' + t.minutes + '<br>' +
                      'seconds: ' + ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
       if(t.total<=0){
         clearInterval(timeinterval);
       }
      },1000);
    }




</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have some styles in your StyleSheet.css? If so, would be nice to share.

Comment: no styles on StyleSheet.css yet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

assign css to your classes (days / hours / mins )etc

```
.days .hours .minutes .seconds {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

if you wanted different elements to have different styles then separate them

```
.days {
border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}

.hours {
border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
}
```

for example.

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_border.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for some reason this doesnt work, must be something wrong with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Whole file below - added an extra break between the elements to further separate them - just remove if you don't want - lines 63/64/65

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
    <style>
        h1{color:brown;
        }
        p
        {font-size:50px;
            color:lightcoral;
        }

        .foo{color:red;
            font-size:50px;

        }

        .days, .hours, .minutes, .seconds {
            border-style: solid !important;
            border-width: 5px !important;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:cyan" "text-align:center">
<h1> </h1>
<h2> </h2>
<div id="clockdiv" class="foo">

   <span class="days"> Days:</span><br>
    Hours: <span class="hours"></span><br>
    Minutes: <span class="minutes"></span><br>
    Seconds: <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
<script>
    var deadline = '7/1/2017';
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

    function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        var Days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
        return {
            'total': t,
            'Days': Days,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };

    }
    function initializeClock(id, endtime){
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        var DaysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
        var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        var timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
            clock.innerHTML = '<span class="days">Days: ' + t.Days + '</span><br /><br />' +
                '<span class="hours">hours: '+ t.hours + '</span><br /><br />' +
                '<span class="minutes">minutes: ' + t.minutes + '</span><br /><br />' +
                '<span class="seconds">seconds: ' + ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
            if(t.total<=0){
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
        },1000);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue was that the JS was over laying the html, so we had to add the class into the JS - that way when it over laid the html, it did so with the classes intact, which then picked up styling from the css